# How to show Angular Material datepicker display format DD-MMM-YYYY like 23-JUL-2019

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material

I have angular material datepicker by default the value is coming like this : 7/23/2019 but I want like this: 23-JUL-2019

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: The [documentation has a section on custom formats](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#customizing-the-parse-and-display-formats)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution from documentation, we can add our custom formats like this:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';
import {MomentDateAdapter} from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import {DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE} from '@angular/material/core';

// Depending on whether rollup is used, moment needs to be imported differently.
// Since Moment.js doesn't have a default export, we normally need to import using the `* as`
// syntax. However, rollup creates a synthetic default module and we thus need to import it using
// the `default as` syntax.
import * as _moment from 'moment';
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-duplicate-imports
import {default as _rollupMoment} from 'moment';

const moment = _rollupMoment || _moment;

// See the Moment.js docs for the meaning of these formats:
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  display: {
    dateInput: 'DD-MMM-YYYY'
  },
};

/** @title Datepicker with custom formats */
@Component({
  selector: 'datepicker-formats-example',
  templateUrl: 'datepicker-formats-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['datepicker-formats-example.css'],
  providers: [
    // `MomentDateAdapter` can be automatically provided by importing `MomentDateModule` in your
    // application's root module. We provide it at the component level here, due to limitations of
    // our example generation script.
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},

    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS},
  ],
})
export class DatepickerFormatsExample {
  date = new FormControl(moment());
}
```

In template:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder="Verbose datepicker" [formControl]="date">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```